# Where is my uploaded file in http://www.posttestserver.com/?

Tags: android, file-upload, http-post, multipart, retrofit2

I used the http://posttestserver.com/post.php  for testing multipart file upload from my android device using retrofit. I got the success response as :

```
Time: Wed, 16 Mar 16 23:14:04 -0700
Source ip: 

Headers (Some may be inserted by server)
REQUEST_URI = /post.php
QUERY_STRING = 
REQUEST_METHOD = POST
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1
REMOTE_PORT = 57241
REMOTE_ADDR = 117.217.235.52
HTTP_USER_AGENT = okhttp/3.0.1
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = gzip
HTTP_CONNECTION = close
HTTP_HOST = posttestserver.com
CONTENT_LENGTH = 610
CONTENT_TYPE = multipart/form-data; boundary=b9c564cd-fcab-48fc-b034-    75ee43c0db90
UNIQUE_ID = VupLLEBaMGUAAHKlJhoAAAAT
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT = 1458195244.3543
REQUEST_TIME = 1458195244

Post Params:
key: 'description' value: 'hello, this is description speaking'
Empty post body.

== Multipart File upload. ==
Received 1 file(s)
 0: posted name=upload
name: 1
type: application/json
error: 0
size: 122
Uploaded File: http://posttestserver.com/files/2016/03/16/f_23.14.04276262399
```

The above last line shows the uploaded file. But opening this link shows the metadata of uploaded file.

```
{"headers":{"namesAndValues":["Content-Disposition","form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"IMG-20160316-WA0004.jpg\""]}}
```

Where can I find the actual uploaded image ?

Answer (score 0):

Tried with ION class its working fine.No image is displayed when clicking on the link mentioned above.

Sharing the code below .

```
                Ion.with(context)
                .load("http://posttestserver.com/post.php").setLogging("MyLogs", Log.VERBOSE)
                .uploadProgressBar(h.progress)
                .setMultipartFile("archive", "image/*", new File(source.getPath()))
                .asString()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.e("Error Result", e.toString());
                        }
                        Log.d("Result", result);
                    }
                });
```